# How to select n rows around a given row

Tags: t-sql, select

I'm trying to select a row, as well as the 5 rows before and after it and return them in a single select statement. Where do I even begin to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define “before” and “after” for database rows?

Comment: Is there an auto increment primary key?

Comment: It's for sql server, oracle, sybase ase, mysql ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `cte` with `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT t.*
    ,      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY OrderColumn)AS RowNum
    FROM Table t
)
SELECT cte.* FROM cte
WHERE RowNum >= @rowToSelect - 5 AND RowNum <= @rowToSelect + 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UNION` query, something like (pseudo-code):

```
SELECT TOP 6 * --include row and 5 rows before
FROM table1
WHERE column1 >= @value
UNION
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM table1
WHERE column1 < @value
```

Answer (score 1):

You quickly fix your problem using [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Make it a result from a subquery and then select the information from that query for the row numbers that you want.